# Reading data out of list == "data1", but I ask to change that "data1" to > "list1data1" its changes it to "list2data1"

Tags: c#, list, contains

Sorry for the vague title, I had no idea how to explain this problem in one sentence. I hope you will understand the problem when looking to my code.

I fill  in two lists (list1 and list2) with a pretty weird method. List1 and List2 are 2D lists. The count of both lists are both 4 (I tested this). The first index of the lists are all filled in and contain the next data: data1, data2, data3, data4 (I tested this). so: `[0][0]` contains `"data1" && [0][1]` contains `"data2" && [0][2]` contains `"data3" && [0][3]` contains "data4". of both lists!!! Now, when I check if the `lists[x][0]` contains "datax", if so: change the name of `[x][0]`. this works at list1 BUT NOT in list2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wholeList.Count; i++)
{
    if (wholeList[i] < someclass.otherlist1.Count) //wholeList[i] are numbers given 
    //by the user, can be betwen 0-7 (0-3 for list1 4-7 for list2)
    {
        list1.Add(someclass.otherlist1[wholeList[i]]);
    }
    else
    {
        list2.Add(someclass.otherlist2[wholeList[i]-someclass.otherlist2.Count]);
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list1[i][0]); //outcome is:
    //data 1
    //data 2
    //data 3
    //data 4
}
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list2[i][0]); //outcome is:
    //data 1
    //data 2
    //data 3
    //data 4
}
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count;i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine("test list 1");
    if (list1[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 1".ToUpper()) || list1[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 2".ToUpper()))
    {
        list1[i][0] = "LIST1DATA1-2";
    }
    else if (list1[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 3".ToUpper()) || list1[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 4".ToUpper()))
    {
        list1[i][0] = "LIST1DATA3-4";
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test list 2");
    if (list2[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 1".ToUpper()) || list2[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 2".ToUpper()))
    {
        list2[i][0] = "LIST2DATA1-2";
    }
    else if (list2[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 3".ToUpper()) || list2[i][0].ToUpper().Contains("data 4".ToUpper()))
    {
        list2[i][0] = "LIST2DATA3-4";
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wtf"); //why it always prints this????
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list1[i][0]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list2[i][0]);
}

//outcome above is:
//LIST2DATA1-2
//LIST2DATA1-2
//LIST2DATA3-4
//LIST2DATA3-4
//wtf
//wtf
//wtf
//wtf
```

How is this possible????

Also when I dont add `"data1"` in `list1[0][0]`. It actually does print the `list2data1-2`.

Comment: What happens if you add the following at the start of your method? `Trace.Assert(!ReferenceEquals(list1, list2));` (You will probably need to add a `using System.Diagnostics;` too.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson nothing happened, same result, or am i using it wrong? im not that good with C#

Comment: Please show declaration of list1 and list2

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Set Breakpoints? single step through your code? Checked expected vs. actual variable contents?

Comment: The text of your question does not match the code! data[a][b] vs data[b][a]

Comment: @wouter Ok, was just checking that `list1` and `list2` weren't referencing the same underlying list (if they were, the Trace.Assert() would have thrown)

Comment: @wouter Please check if "otherlist1" and "otherlist2" is referenced or not. This problem is due to reference I think. Just you need to check if any of list is referenced or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably referencing the same list with two different names (`list1` and `list2`) OR you actually have two different lists, but both referencing the same values. So when you first change the values in `list1` you also change `list2`.
You can check, if two variables are referencing the same object by:

```
object.ReferenceEquals(list1, list2);
```

If that returns false, try also

```
object.ReferenceEquals(list1[0], list2[0]);
```

and

```
object.ReferenceEquals(list1[0][0], list2[0][0]);
```

Comment: `bool returnValue = object.ReferenceEquals(list1, list2);`

Comment: false, true, true, they are indeed refering to the same object, im gonna change this. thank for helping